# how can I show loading spinner when changing router in vue 2

Tags: javascript, vuejs2

I have been trying to show a spinner on each router change in vue 2. I added a flag in created method to show the initial loading and after sometime I stopped the loading spinner. This doesn't work at all.

Is there any other solution to achieve this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You could use a `data` variable e.g. `isLoading` and set it to true by default. Then, in the `mounted` function you can load your stuff and set the variable to false when the data is loaded. In the template you can add a spinner component which binds to `isLoading`. You shouldn't show a spinner on *each* routing change, because there are most often routes which do not have data to load. Show a spinner when the component is loaded but the data is still missing (routing should be instant)

Comment: Thank you for such a nice comment.. :)

Answer (score 2):

You can also use navigation guards to set a beforeEach method that will run before entering each new route: https://router.vuejs.org/en/advanced/navigation-guards.html

Comment: Unfortunately, when using a route in the url initially ('someurl#/foo), `beforeEach` won't get called. Also, `beforeEnter` doesn't have access to `app` either. Any ideas how to show a loading spinner initially per route?