# Accessing app inside beforeRouteEnter

Tags: vue.js, vue-router

I'd like to show some loading animation in the app root while a component prepares to be rendered by vue router.

Already found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44868403/176140), proposing the use of navigation guards, and [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44886812/176140), where the accepted answer shows how to use the `beforeEach` guard to set a variable in `app`, showing a loading animation.

The problem is that **this doesn't work when deep-linking** to some route (initial url includes a route path, such as 'someurl#/foo'). The `beforeEach` guard simply doesn't get called then.

So i switched to the loaded component's `beforeRouteEnter` guard, which would also allow me to show the loading animation for some components only:

app:

```
var app = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: { loading: false }
  router: router
});
```

component:

```
var Foo = { 
  template: '<div>bar</div>',
  beforeRouteEnter: function(to, from, next) {
    app.loading = true; // 'app' unavailable when deep-linking
    // do some loading here before calling next()...
    next();
  }
}
```

But then i found that when deep-linking to the component, `app` isn't available in `beforeRouteEnter`, as it gets called very early in the initialisation process.

I don't want to set `loading` to `true` inside the app data declaration, as i might decide at some point to deep-link to another route, whose component doesn't need a loading animation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Found a workaround using Vue.nextTick:

```
beforeRouteEnter: function(to, from, next) {
    Vue.nextTick(function(){
      // now app is available
      app.loading = true;
      // some loading to happen here...
      seTimeout(function(){            
        app.loading = false;
        next();  
    }, 1000); 
  })
}
```

Feels a little hacky, so would be thankful for other suggestions.

Find a demo of this solution here:
https://s.codepen.io/schellmax/debug/aYvXqx/GnrnbVPBXezr#/foo

Answer (score 9):

I believe, your solution is correct. However, I would suggest using next() function instead. As written in vue-router docs.
https://router.vuejs.org/en/advanced/navigation-guards.html

> The beforeRouteEnter guard does NOT have access to this, because the guard is called before the navigation is confirmed, thus the new entering component has not even been created yet.
>
> However, you can access the instance by passing a callback to next. The callback will be called when the navigation is confirmed, and the component instance will be passed to the callback as the argument:

```
beforeRouteEnter (to, from, next) {
  next(vm => {
    vm.$root.loading = true;
  })
}
```

Comment: Thanks, i already found this, but at the point 'next()' is run, it's already too late, as i can't have the router wait for some data to load then anymore

Answer (score 0):

What about using `beforeRouteLeave` to trigger the loading then have the component toggle it off in `mounted`.

For the initial load of the app you could have

**app**:

```
var app = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data() => ({ loading: true }),
  mounted() { this.loading: false },
  router: router
});
```

then for your components

**component**:

```
var Foo = { 
  template: '<div>bar</div>',
  mounted() {
    app.loading = false;
  },
  beforeRouteLeave(to, from , next) {
    switch(to){
      case COMPONENT_TO_SHOW_LOADING_ON:
      case OTHER_COMPONENT:
        app.loading = true;
      default:
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but if I understand correctly I see 2 problems here: *1)* `beforeRouteLeave` won't get called on any component initially (there is no component rendered yet) and *2)* referencing otherwise unrelated components this way is some sort of "tight coupling" that should be avoided