# Vue Router beforeResolve executing in unexpected time

Tags: vue.js, vue-router

My question is about this behavior that reacts differently than I expected, and I would like to know how can I reach the behavior I want.

First of all, Vue Router has some guards/hooks I can use when it navigates to its routes inside a SPA (Single Page Application). I am trying to display a loading screen element when I click a link to navigate to another route, and hide the element as soon as the component is shown. I see many questions (e.g. [#1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44868403/how-can-i-show-loading-spinner-when-changing-router-in-vue-2), [#2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44886812/how-to-display-a-loading-animation-while-a-lazy-loaded-route-component-is-bein)) telling to use "beforeResolve" and "afterEach" guards/hooks. But then I am having a problem.

What happens (the problem)?

- I click the link to another route/page/component.
- Router starts a Network request.
- Application waits until the requested page is fetched.
- Router triggers beforeResolve.
- Router triggers afterEach (<1ms after beforeResolve)
- Fetched page is rendered.

What do I expect to happen?

- I click the link to another page.
- Router triggers beforeResolve and shows the loading screen.
- Router starts a Network request.
- Application waits until the requested page is fetched.
- Router triggers afterEach to hide the loading screen and shows the fetched page.

To reproduce it:

1. Create a Vue application with vue-router: `npm init vue@latest`
2. Choose the router only, say no to all other options, they don't matter.
3. Add these lines to main.js:

```
router.beforeResolve(()=>console.log("Before Resolve"));
router.afterEach(()=>console.log("After Each"));
```

4. Finish to install and `npm run dev` the application, if you haven't done that yet.
5. Now in the browser you can open Dev Tools and go to the Network tab. Set "Disable cache" to true and set throttling to something slow. Instant requests will not show the problem, we need a slow connection to see it.
6. Open the application page, and open the Dev Tools Console tab.
7. Click the "About" router link to navigate to another page.
8. Watch the console.

Here is my problem: once the browser loads the "About" component, it triggers beforeResolve, afterEach, and render the component, all at the same time. The loading screen would not show at any moment (show and hide too fast).

I was expecting it would first trigger beforeResolve, then fetch the page and awaits the load, then call afterEach.

Just watching for some RouterLink click event is not the best. I would love to use the hooks, if possible, as it would care about manual navigation for example.

**So did the behavior change over time? What did I do wrong? Is there a hook I can use that triggers as soon as I click the Router link?**

Comment: why not use beforeEach?
https://router.vuejs.org/guide/advanced/navigation-guards.html
"router.beforeResolve. ..similar to ...beforeEach .. but resolve guards are called right before the navigation is confirmed, after all in-component guards and async route components are resolved"

Comment: @mech You can post it as an answer, because it solve my problem. It would be appreciated if you know and include WHY the "beforeResolve" does not work. Most tutorials I found were using "beforeResolve", but it seem "beforeEach" is the right event. It's probably my non-native English failing, but I don't understand the part of the documentation that says "[...]after all in-component guards and async route components are resolved.", and why the event is called after the fetch.